# How do I automate formatting a cell based on another cell's value without using Paintbrush feature

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns, **L:L (targets)** and **K:K (current numbers)**.

I want to create a conditional format that matches column K's cell format with the relative L's format (for example, if L3 is currency then K3 is currency as well). I can use paint brush feature but it'd be too time consuming and we have 20+ sheet to replicate.

I think the answer for this might be VBA since Excel does not natively provide a feature to format a cell based on another cell's format.But I'm not sure how.

[image]

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 3):

- If you only want to replicate `all formats` from column K to column L

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.PasteSpecial method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144238)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Sht
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)
            .Range("K3:K" & LastRow).Copy
            .Range("L3:L" & LastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End With
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

[image]

---

- If you only want to replicate `number formats` from column K to column L

```vb
Sub CopyNumFormat()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, arrData
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Sht
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp)
            .Range("K3:K" & LastRow).Copy
            With .Range("L3:L" & LastRow)
                arrData = .Value
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                .Value = arrData
            End With
        End With
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! yes exactly, I only wanted to replicate  the number formats from K:K to L:L, thanks for sending the Method Link I had trouble explaining/googling that!. Thank you again for the help :D